# Initializing resources based on route and/or module

Tags: php, zend-framework, resources, request

I'm using Zend Framework 1.8/1.9's `Zend_Application` and the resource system to initilize a bunch of resources. I would like to only load certain .ini files based on the module being requested – for example, loading "help.ini" if (and only if) the CMS module is requested ("/cms"). Trouble is, I'm not sure how to access the request object in a `Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract` subclass.

In one of my resources (for initializing custom routes for the CMS), I use a hacky little util to get the module (below), and then I add custom routes if it matching the "cms" module name:

```
/**
 * Grab the module name without a request instance
 *
 * @return string  The module name
 */
public static function getModuleName()
{
    $uri = ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/");
    $module = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, "/"));
    return $module;
}
```

---

```
$module = Typeoneerror_Util_Strings::getModuleName();

// -- only attach certain routes if using cms module
if ($module == Typeoneerror_Constants::CMS_MODULE)
{
    ...
```

I'd like this to be more "Zend-y", i.e. like a controller plugin, where a request object is passed to the class:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $router = $this->__front->getRouter();
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question: From your `ResourceAbstract` subclass, you can retrieve the front controller like so:

```
 $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();
 $bootstrap->bootstrap('frontController'); // make sure it's initialized
 $fc = $bootstrap->getResource('frontController');
 // Then I'm sure you know how to get the request from there.
```

**However,** the request object is typically not constructed until the `dispatch()` method of `Zend_Controller_Front` is called. So, in short, the request object you are looking for does not yet exist. So, you *could* manually construct an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` then pass it along to your front controller.

**But**, nothing has been routed yet either, so none of the params you're used to seeing the request object have been populated.

Basically, anything that happens in `Zend_Application` is *way* too early in your application's life cycle to do what you want.

I would highly recommend doing your module-specific loading in the `routeShutdown` hook of a front controller plugin.

Comment: "routeShutdown() is called after the router finishes routing the request." - Exactly what I was looking for! Guess I should've done more research on the "life-cycle" of the controller plugin events. Well done!